# Differences between default fields definition

Tags: db2, db2-zos

`Db2 Z/OS Version 11.01 and 12.`

I am verifying that the structure of some tables is equal on more customers/environments.
I noticed that the default value is the only aspect that differs between many tables

For Example - Table "Order" Columns "PRICE"

```
  Environment 1 -> DECIMAL(18,3) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
  Environment 2 -> DECIMAL(18,3) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0 
  Environment 3 -> DECIMAL(18,3) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0.0
```

I am not sure if i have to consider theese "definitions" as technically and functionally equivalent or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent in this case. You can find the default values for different data types if you don't specify the values explicitly in the link (
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_defaultvalues.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for a decimal(18,3) column, all three are functionally equivalent.

The default ends up being `000000000000000.000`